# Set back to default radio button

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, groupbox

I am working with VB.net and am trying to create a Clear button.

I have everything worked out with my labels, checkboxes, and textboxes.  The problem I have is working with the 3 radio buttons in a group box.  I want it to default back to the default of radButton1 when pressing the Clear button.  I thought that the code would just be:

```
radButton1.Checked = True
```

but that is not working.  Any thoughts?

**************Adding more info***************

Here is the code that I am working with right now for the clear button.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmWMMainForm


Dim intWMTotal As Integer

Private Sub btnWMExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWMExit.Click
    'closes the program

    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnWMClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWMClear.Click
    'Clears all information

    txtWMFee.Text = String.Empty
    lblWMAdditional.Text = String.Empty
    lblWMDiscount.Text = String.Empty
    lblWMDues.Text = String.Empty
    chkWMGolf.Checked = False
    chkWMRaquetball.Checked = False
    chkWMTennis.Checked = False
    radWMRegular.Checked = True


End Sub

Private Sub btnWMCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWMCalc.Click


    Dim intWMFee As Integer
    Dim intWMGolf As Integer = 25
    Dim intWMTennis As Integer = 30
    Dim intWMRacquetball As Integer = 20
    Dim intWMMilitary As Integer = -10
    Dim intWMSenior As Integer = -5

    Integer.TryParse(txtWMFee.Text, intWMFee)


End Sub

Private Sub radWMMilitary_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radWMMilitary.CheckedChanged
    If radWMMilitary.Checked = True Then
        lblWMThankyou.Visible = True
    Else
        lblWMThankyou.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CancelKeys(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtWMFee.KeyPress
    ' allows the text box to accept only numbers and
    ' the Backspace key

    If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso
        e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        ' cancel the key
        e.Handled = True

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you have any other code which affects the `Checked` state of the RadioButtons? I tested what you stated with a minimal form and it behaved as you expected.

Comment: You're doing something else that is preventing the radiobutton from being checked? Your code works for me.

Comment: Here is more of the code.  Thanks!

Comment: @WarrenMcAllister Do you have any *other* code which affects the `Checked` state of the RadioButtons?

Comment: I'll post ALL of my code that I have so far.  One sec.

Comment: the radio button that I have as default is radWMRegular.  The other two are radWMSenior and radWMMillitary.

Comment: I would suggest adding a handler for that `RadioButton's` `CheckedChanged` event and putting a breakpoint on it to see whether it actually does get raised.

Comment: You were exactly correct jmcilhinney!  Thank you! =D